# Do we know Grawp's real name?

Tags: harry-potter

[Grawp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubeus_Hagrid#Grawp) is [Hagrid's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubeus_Hagrid) younger full-giant half-brother; however he is called Grawp because when Hagrid found him, that's what he called himself since he couldn't pronounce his real name:

> “Well — half-brother,” amended Hagrid. “Turns out me mother
>   took up with another giant when she left me dad, an’ she went an’ had
>   Grawp here —”
>   “Grawp?” said Harry.
>   “Yeah . . . well, tha’s what it sounds like when he says his name,”
>   said Hagrid anxiously. “He don’ speak a lot of English. . . . I’ve bin
>   tryin’ ter teach him. . . . Anyway, she don’ seem ter have liked him
>   much more’n she liked me. . . . See, with giantesses, what counts is
>   producin’ good big kids, and he’s always been a bit on the runty side
>   fer a giant — on’y sixteen foot —”
> <sub>*-Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix, Chapter Thirty (Grawp).*</sub>

**Is it ever revealed anywhere what Grawp's real name is?**

Comment: And as a corollary, why couldn’t he speak proper? I mean, with his size, he can hardly be an infant… Whatever language the other, adult giants spoke, he ought at least to be able to speak that at more than grunting level.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I don't think there's any implication that Grawp couldn't speak Giant (it may have a proper name) properly, but that Hagrid couldn't clearly decipher the sounds of that language, nor indeed of the name of his half-brother in that language. I mean, we have this even among human languages all the time, just listen to the commentators during the olympics, or British news reporters trying to get their tongues around Mahmoud Ahmadinejad

Comment: @Au101 But Hagrid (or Madame Maxime) was perfectly capable of deciphering the names of the other giants, which were presumably also in Giant. You’d also expect, if Grawp could actually speak Giant, that he’d _speak_ it during the books: monolingual children (and he does seem to be a child, at least intellectually) tend to simply speak their own language to others, assuming that everyone can understand them. Grawp never said _anything_ except grunts and growls and the four or so words Hagrid had managed to teach him.

Comment: The simple answer is no.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet the other giants either spoke English or had someone to translate if i remember correctly, at least the 2 cheif giants they name.

Comment: @Himarm Yes, they had translators, who should also have been able to tell Hagrid what Grawp’s name was—they clearly told him enough about him and his mother for him to realise that Grawp was Fridwulfa’s son. My point was that Grawp _never says a single word_ in the three books in which he appears, apart from what Hagrid has taught him. He doesn’t babble in Giant, he doesn’t mix Giant and English, nothing. He gives absolutely no indication whatsoever that he knew how to speak at all before Hagrid tried to teach him.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Grawp does seem to be a child by giant perspectives (and by his actions as you pointed out). But he has spent some time with Hagrid and travelled with him all the way back to Hogwarts. As young as he seems, maybe Grawp did have enough sense to realize that Hagrid wouldn't understand the language he was trying to speak and hence resorted to grunting and growling to get himself understood.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### No.

We don't know much about Grawp, and his real/original name has never been revealed, not even by JK Rowling on Twitter as far as I can find.

We *do* have a little more 'behind the scenes' information than is in the books, namely the following notes JKR made while writing *HP and the Order of the Phoenix*, which she released several years ago and which have been kindly transcribed by [HP Lexicon](http://www.hp-lexicon.org/about/sources/jkr.com/jkr-com-trans-ootpchart.html):

[image]

Sadly this provides us with almost no extra information about Grawp, even though he and Hagrid get an entire column to themselves (among only 6-7 columns for different strands of the plot!)